# When to use Wave Bonding vs Raft on a 3D print?

Tags: rafts

I use a Micro3D printer, running on OctoPi (yay!) (although this question should be relevant to any 3D printer that offers these features) and have options for raft and wave bonding.

Are there best case scenarios for when it is appropriate to use (or *not* use) either?  Can/should they ever both be used at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After additional research, it seems that using both at the same time is ill-advised (more like pointless).

Wave bonding is best suited for larger prints, primarily to prevent warping of the initial layer.

Rafts appear to be recommended regardless, other than for advanced users.

Comment: Where did you read the conclusion "Rafts appear to be recommended regardless, other than for advanced users."? As I have read rafts are primarily for adhesion for ABS and for bonding small footprint elements.

Comment: Does anyone use rafts anymore? I thought that was to compensate for uneven/unlevel beds. I always use a brim with plastics.